# Salesforce Chatter &Activities

Tags: chatter, activities, sfmcadmin

Can someone please explain to me, why Activities(Log a Call, New Task, New Event ) are automatically being recorded in Chatter. This happens at least on Leads, Account Object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why activities (**Log a Call**, **New Task**, **New Event**) are automatically being recorded in **Chatter** is because of the `feed tracking feature`. Feed tracking lets you choose which field changes and record operations to post to the Chatter feed. By default, feed tracking is enabled for activities and some standard objects, such as leads and accounts.

[You can see the list of tracked fields and actions for each object in the Feed Tracking setting.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_feed_tracking_overview.htm&type=5)

If you want to disable feed tracking for activities or other objects, you can follow these steps:

- From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Feed Tracking, and then select Feed Tracking.
- Select the object that you want to disable feed tracking for, such as Activities, Leads, or Accounts.
- Deselect Enable Feed Tracking.
- Click Save.

Note that disabling feed tracking for an object also disables feed tracking for all its child objects.

For example, if you disable feed tracking for accounts, feed tracking is also disabled for contacts, opportunities, and cases related to accounts.

Comment: Hi, Tushar, deslecting Enable feed tracking means I no longer can have access to Chatter but the requirement is that Chatter should be there, but just that Activities should not be recorded. Chatter could be used for other purposes, like tagging group members, when there are Activities that is being recorded on Chatter, I have the same record twice, for example if I log a call in Activities, I dont want to see it in Chatter but I need Chatter function enabled